# Styling DropdownListFor when Error appears

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application the user must select Product Categories from a DropDownList. So what I want to do is, if he doesen't select a category and tries to send his order, the DropDownList should be highlighted so he sees, that he has to select a category. My problem now is, not one the attempts I tried to style this DropDownList, did work yet. So I hope you can help me out or tell me where the problem is:

CSS-File:

```
.field-validation-error {color: #ffb3b3;}
    .field-validation-valid {display: none;}
    .input-validation-error {border: 1px solid #f00; background-color: #ffb3b3;}
    .select.input-validation-valid { display: none;}
    .select.input-validation-error { color: #ffb3b3; }
    .validation-summary-error {font-weight: bold; color: #ffb3b3;}
    .validation-summary-valid {display: none}
```

DropdownListFor in the view:

```
@if (Request.Form["SendOrder"] != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProductCategory))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PC,
        new SelectList(Model.ProductCategory.OrderBy(m => m.PCNumber),
        "", "CategoryName",
        new {@class = "field-validation-error, input-validation-error,
        select.input-validation-error" }), "Select a Category")
}
else
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PC,
    new SelectList(Model.ProductCategory.OrderBy(m => m.PCNumber),
    "", "CategoryName"), "Select a category")
}
```

Comment: use the help of bootstrap classes and put your dropdown inisde a div and apply bootstrap class to the div based on your conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this, the problem is solved and the solution can be found [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2103626.aspx?How+to+set+a+background+color+for+DropdownlistFor+)